# How to, inside a QTreeView, delete a selected row?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

I tried to delete a selected row of a QTreeView with an event.
This is the function:

```
bool TargetEventFilter::deleteselect(bool delete)
{
    auto select= examplemodel->selectionModel()->currentIndex();
    auto parent= select.parent();
    int row= select.row();
    bool remove = examplemodel->model()->removeRow(row, parent);
    return remove ;
}
```

So my problem is:
The event is working (tried with the debugger).The Parent and the indext is always right. But the problem is that the selected row will not be deleted. In "return remove" i get a "false".

Comment: How do you know that `examplemodel->selectionModel()->currentIndex()` is valid? You are not checking if it's valid, so you don't know :) The idea is that any time you use a function that may return a value with the meaning of *invalid value*, you have to check against it. It's of course debatable whether returning invalid values is a desirable design decision in an API - in modern code one would use `std::optional` or a similar construct, but this part of Qt's API is over a decade old and they decided against it.

Answer (score 0):

why you do not used [CurrentIndex](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#currentIndex) ?

```
 bool remove = examplemodel->model()->removeRow(row, select);
```

Comment: what you mean? i used it already above and then seperated select into row and parent?

Comment: it seams that your QTreeView can not find selected index.you can use "QItemSelectionModel::currentIndex()" instead of "QModelIndex::parent()" to find "QModelIndex"